# Thesis biblography

Tags: bibliographies

I am using the template of the my department. Here is the part of the latex code:

```
...
\chapter{Conclusion}
\input{conclusion.tex}
% References in Bibtex format goes into below indicated file with .bib extension
\bibliography{thesis_references}
% You can use full name of authors, however most likely some of the Bibtex entries you will find, will use abbreviated first names
% If you don't want to correct each of them by hand, you can use abbreviated style for all of the references

\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\appendix
%
% If you are a Ph.D. Student you need to insert a CV at the end of you thesis
% Check vita.tex for a simple CV template in Latex
\input{vita.tex}
\end{document}
```

I added the all chapters creating the different .tex files and using the input comment. 
I don't want to change the template dramatically but need to add references. How can I fix the problem?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What is exactly the problem? The code fragment you show us should work, normally.

Comment: I dont know how will I add the references. For the chapters I created .tex files. For the references should I create .bib file or just write on here?

Comment: Please tell us if your bib entries are contained in a file called `thesis_references.bib` (note the ".bib" extension). In addition, please tell us if you have any `\cite` instructions in any parts of the main body of your dissertation. Finally, assuming (say) that the main tex file is called `main.tex`, do tell us if you run latex main, bibatex main, followed by latex main twice more.

Comment: It's better to create a `.bib`. `JabRef` can help you do it without syntax errors.

Comment: You should definitely make the (fairly minor) effort to learn the basics of BibTeX. Only by using a software tool such as BibTeX will you be assured that (a) every citation call-out in the body of the text will correspond to a formatted bibliographic entry and (b) there will no redundant entries in the formatted bibliography, i.e., formatted entries that aren't cited anywhere in the document.